# CSS absolute not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get some icons to align in the middle of the screen and I am not sure why it isn't working
CSS:

```
#Main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='Main'>
            <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/OwnCloud/" target="_self"><img alt="OwnCloud" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/owncloud.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://me.rx14.co.uk:8080/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/jenkins.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/solder/"><img alt="Solder" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/solder.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a><br />
            <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/wx/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/wx.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/munin/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/munin.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/munin-live/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/munin_live.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:[image: Result of code!]

Comment: looks correct - the top left corner is at the 50%, 50% positions you requested. The absolute is working exactly as its supposed to - you just misinterpreted what it's supposed to do.

Comment: When positioned absolutely, elements coordinates are based off the top left corner, not the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give to the element

```
margin-left:-[ELEMENT_WIDTH/2]px
```

and

```
margin-top:-[ELEMENT_HEIGHT/2]px
```

In your case (based on the width and height of those images) can be:

```
#Main { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-375px 0 0 -375px; }
```

(this if elements inside got no margins, same width and height, etc)

or this:

```
#Main { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-255px 0 0 -383px; }
```

(this is your case as suggested by EJanuszewski)

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand what I did wrong now thanks to this post sevenseacat and Duy-Anh!

Answer (score 2):

As Kevin said, you need negative margins to do that, see this example below.

Your #main div has a width of 766, divide that by 2 = 383, that's your negative margin-left.
It has a height of 510, divide that by 2 = 255, that's the negative margin-top.

http://jsfiddle.net/EPs2L/

HTML:

```
    <div id='Main'>
        <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/OwnCloud/" target="_self"><img alt="OwnCloud" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/owncloud.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
        <a href="http://me.rx14.co.uk:8080/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/jenkins.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
        <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/solder/"><img alt="Solder" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/solder.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a><br />
        <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/wx/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/wx.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
        <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/munin/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/munin.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>&nbsp;
        <a href="https://me.rx14.co.uk/munin-live/"><img alt="" src="https://me.rx14.co.uk/img/munin_live.png" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" /></a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-383px;
    margin-top:-255px;
}
```